# Messaging exception raised: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal semicolon, not in group in string

Tags: java, email

In my original email message content, I'm getting 'To' address field like this, for example To: abc@gmail.com;efg@gmail.com;hij@gmail.com 
     When I tried to read this to address in my Java program with this >>

```
message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)
```

I got the below exception

Messaging exception raised:

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal semicolon, not in group in string ``abc@gmail.com;efg@gmail.com;hij@gmail.com'' at position 21
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:929)
    at `enter code here`javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parseHeader(InternetAddress.java:663)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:733)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:565)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please pass the multiple email addresses as an argument to the method instead of using semicolon

void addRecipients(Message.RecipientType type, Address[] addresses) 
   throws MessagingException
   {

   }

Eg: 
// create a new String array
String[] recipients = new String[4];

// add email addresses
recipients[0] = first@gmail.com
recipients[1] = second@gmail.com
recipients[2] = third@gmail.com
recipients[3] = fourth@gmail.com

// inside of try block instead of using addRecipient() 
// use addRecipients()

// specify the type of field(TO, CC ,BCC)
// pass the array of email ids of recipients
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));


Please follow the below link,it will be helpful :
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-email-using-java-program/
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But my original content has 
To:brianb@cowsglobal.com;mikef@cowsglobal.com;anaf@cowsglobal.com how can I read from that in my java program

Comment: Instead ofpaasing receipients with semicolon separated, use a string array to put each recepient in it. like String[] recipients = new String[4];

recipients[0] = brianb@cowsglobal.com
recipients[1] = mikef@cowsglobal.com
recipients[2] = anaf@cowsgloba‌​l.com
recipients[3] = fourth@gmail.com

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

Comment: Actually my problem is not with WRITING my email address. I need to READ from a message content.

Comment: Actually i'm not passing the recipients, I'm trying to READ it

Comment: see if this helps,also there is problem with semicolon so replace it with , and check List<String> toAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
for (Address address : recipients) {
    toAddresses.add(address.toString());
}

Comment: List<String> toAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
     Address[] recipients = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
for (Address address : recipients) 
{ 
    toAddresses.add(address.toString());
} 

Still I face this exception